# Easy way to toggle something without global variables

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I feel bad for asking this as it is  a very easy question. I want the cycleBackground function to alternate between `changeBackground("#firstbg", img.src)` and `changeBackground("#secondbg", img.src)`

```
    cycleBackground = ()->
        img = new Image()
        img.src = '/assets/'+Math.floor(Math.random()*50)+'.jpg)'
        img.onLoad = ()->
            changeBackground("#firstbg", img.src)
```

I was about to create a global var called "selected" 
and make it equal "#firstbg" and if selected is "#firstbg" then change it to "#secondbg" so that everytime cycleBackground is called it changes the background of whichever element hasn't already been changed. I know this is bad coding practice, what would be a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new variable in the same scope as your function; either `cycleBackground` or `changeBackground`, whichever. This is completely fine. CoffeeScript wraps the entire compiled file in an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) and doesn't introduce any global variable unless you explicitly attach them to the global object (`window.selected = ...` for example).

```
selected = 'first'

cycleBackground = ()->
  img = new Image()
  img.src = '/assets/'+Math.floor(Math.random()*50)+'.jpg)'
  img.onLoad = ()->
    selected = (if selected == 'first' then 'second' else 'first')
    changeBackground("##{selected}bg", img.src)
```

Comment: in the example it looks like selected is in global scope

Comment: It isn't. CoffeeScript wraps the entire file in an IIFE. To add a variable to global scope, you would need `window.selected = ...`.

Comment: Note that, if CoffeeScript *didn't* do this, you would already be introducing a global variable: `cycleBackground`.

Comment: this is a great answer. I learned two new tricks about js from it. didnt know about this "#{}"

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a variable `x` that holds what image you are looking at currently, and do something like this:

```
x = 0; 
img.onLoad = ()->
   x = Math.abs(x-1); # toggle
   changeBackground("#" + ['firstbg','secondbg'][x], img.src);
```

Note: I don't know where `x` would live because I know absolutely nothing about CoffeeScript.

Comment: *"Note: I don't know where x would live because I know absolutely nothing about CoffeeScript."* ... then do you really think you should be suggesting answers?

Comment: @meagar It is still a valid solution, and `x` lives in the same scope as your suggested solution. The question was tagged JavaScript as well.